# On Linux, how to disable mouse for a second using POSIX shell, without waiting for the second and do some job immediately?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, screenshot, sleep

**TL;DR**: On Linux, how to disable mouse for a second using POSIX shell, without waiting for the second and do some job immediately?

---

OS: Linux Mint 18.3 64-bit Cinnamon with LightDM display manager and Mutter (Muffin) window manager, X11 windowing system.

---

Script environment: `dash`.

---

I need to:

1. Do something (*does not matter what exactly for purposes of this question, but you can read [the full script on Core Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/187172/104270)*).
2. **Disable mouse for a second. But the script must continue. This is very important.**
3. Run an application ([Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/) in general print screen mode) immediately.

**Rationale**: Because of [Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/) probably contains a bug, the mouse can't be moving just before the print screen, or else it usually results in something like this:

[image: lightshot_bug_when_mouse_moving]

Comment: This question should specify your windowing system. An answer for X11 will be different than an answer for Qt/E, which will be different from an answer for Wayland or an answer for GPM+console. This makes a *much bigger difference* than whether your shell is baseline POSIX sh or ksh/bash/whatever.

Comment: There is your problem! **"TL;DR"** Maybe if you took the time to read it all, you wouldn't be confused anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Suppose, that on my system, the mouse device ID equals 12. Then a function doing the trick would appear as follows in a POSIX shell script:

```
my_mouse_device_id=12

disable_mouse_for_a_second()
{
    if xinput --disable "$1" 2> /dev/null
    then
        (
            sleep 1s
            xinput --enable "$1"
        ) &
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

# example usage
if disable_mouse_for_a_second "$my_mouse_device_id"
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

---

## Long story

1. You need to find the mouse device ID using:

   ```
   xinput list --short
   ```
2. [This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52470/126755) helped me a lot, for instance in that the following is deprecated:

   ```
   xinput --set-int-prop
   ```
3. We need to run these two commands afterward:

   > ```
   > sleep 1s
   > xinput --enable "$my_mouse_device_id"
   > ```

   the tricky part is that we need:

   - a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) `(` ... `)`
   - a background job `&`

   for that to work properly.
4. From the practical standpoint, all we need to do is to wrap it up in one nice function.

Comment: I would put the restoration of proper mouse operations into a `trap EXIT`.

Comment: @ndim Feel free to add your modified solution based on mine. I don't mind, I welcome it. Or you could directly modify my answer. The thing is, I don't have experience with `TRAP` in shell scripts. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please inform me, if there is something wrong with the `trap` handling.

Comment: @jarno Hello Jarno, I admit that first change (one trap line) was quite good, but since I do not have time right now, please post your own separate solution, ok? I repeat, it was too drastic an attempt for change, and I merely do not have time to test it. I hope you'll get is in a good way and will post your own solution then, which I will upvote once I get here again. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I added some signal handling to OP's answer, so here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
my_mouse_device_id=12

disable_mouse_for_a_second()
{
    if xinput --disable "$1" 2> /dev/null
    then
        (
            # ensure the device will not be left disabled
            id=$1
            trap 'xinput --enable "$id"; trap - EXIT; exit' \
            EXIT TERM INT HUP
            sleep 1s
        ) &
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

# example usage
if disable_mouse_for_a_second "$my_mouse_device_id"
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

Note that `{` ... `}` seem to work as replacements of `(` ... `)` here, if you prefer, but there will be a sub-shell anyway.

You have to store `$1` in a variable (here `id`) because otherwise at least Dash shell would not know it on EXIT.

I refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/520041/111181) on signal hadling.

Comment: Upvoted, won't probably test, though, so little time lately. Cheers.

Comment: If you save it as `test.sh` in current directory, one testcase is `/bin/sh -c ./test.sh & sleep 0.5; pkill --signal TERM --pgroup $!`.

Comment: Anyway, it is not probable that the process would be terminated unintentionally during that one second.